# To check if database has item, if not insert

Tags: php, sql

I have an form, where is field called team.

```
<input type="text" name="team" id="team" />
```

I would like to inser data from that field IF that same team isn't in database yet.

Basically if user writes 'Chelsea' and that is already in database table then nothing basically happends but if it's not there yet, then it's inserted in to database table tt_clubs.

Can I check that if it's already there somehow? I'm rookie with SQL still :/

EDIT also it shouldn't matter if users writes 'chelsea' or 'Chelsea' or 'chElsea'.. all those should be same.

EDIT table structure is just, 'id' <- automatic and 'Team name'

Comment: please post table Teams structure

Answer (score 2):

### The easy way

I believe that [`INSERT IGNORE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) would solve this problem:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO tt_clubs (team) VALUES ('Chelsea');
```

If the name already exists in the table then the insert will simply be ignored.

Also if you have not already done so set the `team` field to be a unique key:

```
ALTER TABLE tt_clubs ADD UNIQUE(team);
```

### Another way

Attempt to select the value first:

```
SELECT id
FROM tt_clubs
WHERE team LIKE 'Chelsea'
```

Then in PHP you can check how many rows have been returned. If there is one then don't run the insert statement otherwise insert the team name.

Answer (score 1):

You can use solution like this:

1. Use ci collation for you table. CI means case-insensitive
2. Add Unique KEY on this field which is store CHELSEA.
3. Use Insert IGNORE INTO teams(field1) VALUES('Chelsea')

Another way:

1. Select row from db by this field - select id from teams where field1 = 'Chelsea'.
2. If row empty Insert a new row.

Comment: So the 'Team name' field is unique key? And not the id what usually is? Can I have multiple unique keys, nope?

Comment: `id` = Primary Key and `team` = Unique Key. By default the PK is unique.

Comment: Yes. You add several UNIQUE keys.

Answer (score 0):

It totally depends on the DBMS. Oracle, doesn't have the `INSERT IGNORE` clause. I'd do a `MERGE`:

```
MERGE INTO my_table
USING ( SELECT 1 from dual )
ON UPPER( team_name ) = UPPER( user_input )
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT
VALUES ( user_input )
```